# Python. Работа с неориентированным графом и путь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вечера. Такая проблема, при выводе пути с помощью данного кода выводится лишняя точка графа в самом конце. Как избавиться от лишней точки при выводе пути?

```
 print("Введите кол-во точек графа: ")   
    n = int(input())
    print("Заполните матрицу смежности:")
    matrix=[]
    matrix = [[int(input())
       for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
    print(matrix)

graf={i:set()for i in range(n)}
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
         if matrix[i][j] == 1:
            graf[i].add(j)
            graf[j].add(i)
print(graf)

distance=[None]*n
begin=int(input())
end=int(input())
distance[begin]=0
q = deque([begin])
way = []
way.append(begin)
while q:
    n = len(way)
    k = q.popleft()    
    for t in graf[k]:
        if distance[t] is None:
            distance[t] = distance[k]+1
            q.append(t)
            way.append(t)

print(distance[end])
print(way)
```

Приведу пример:[image]

Выбираем стартовой точкой 0,конечной 3. По итогу выводится сколько шагов он по-сути сделал и путь от 0 через 1 в 3,но при этом выводится лишняя 2,которая указана во множестве точки 3. Как избавиться от 2?

Альтернативный пример для большего понимания:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так например, `way[:-1]` :)

Comment: в print, куда же еще

Comment: Ну да. Только жалко,что оно работает только тут.

Comment: Просто если путь подлиннее,то при выведении очередной точки оно может и в середине лишнюю точку вывести.

Comment: Добавил еще пример.Опять же 2 лишняя. Тут костылями не исправишь. Тут корень проблемы нужно найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример поиска пути в графе. У вас некорректно реализован поиск в глубину.

```
def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not start in graph.keys():
        return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath: return newpath
    return None

print(find_path(graf,0,3,path=[]))
```

Comment: То есть,в моем коде реализован поиск в глубину,вместо поиска в ширину,т.е. пути графа,верно?

Comment: Вы с очередью запутались немного.

Comment: Так у меня поиск в ширину в коде или в глубину? Это важно просто)

Comment: Я распознал некий микс. Не поручусь на 100%, что прямо в глубину. Все зависит от того, что вы хотели реализовать)

Comment: Хотел просто реализовать поиск пути, по идее через обход в ширину,но миксанул.

Comment: Можете подсказать, в чем может быть проблема при выводе? Оно выводит лишнее значение.

Вроде работает и хорошо,только этот нюанс бы решить.

Comment: Она выводит лишнюю точку, так как вы неверно реализовали поиск пути)